# microtype does not load particular configuration file

Tags: microtype

The following example via XeLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

produces a log file containing:

```
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
...
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `TeXGyreTermes' (encoding: TU).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
```

If I replace the main font as `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}`, I get the following log:

```
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
...
(".../latex/microtype\mt-PalatinoLinotype.cfg"
File: mt-PalatinoLinotype.cfg 2012/03/10 v1.0 microtype config. file: Palatino 
Linotype and similar fonts (LBD)
)
```

Similar issues are observed under LuaLaTeX as well.

It is clear that `microtype` is not able to automatically load the configuration file for Times-like font family. Is this a bug? How can I enforce the particular configuration?

Note that simply writing `\LoadMicrotypeFile{ptm}` does not change the settings (e.g., protrusion for the uppercase `Y` in Times is supposed to be more aggressive than the generic setting).

Comment: There's no cfg file that supports TU encoding and Times-like fonts.

Comment: @egreg I see, though this is rather confusing. Table 3 of the documentation has a Times entry with a footnote “h Aliases: txfonts (txr), qfonts/QuasiTimes, TeX Gyre Termes (qtm), newtx, tempora”. Apparently, this “TG Termes” was not what I thought it was. Now I see that there are two entries of “TeX Gyre Pagella” which point to two different classes of encoding, and one of them refers to OpenType “Palatino Linotype”…